# What is the meaning of numeric_limits<double>::digits10

Tags: c++, stl

What is the precise meaning of numeric_limits::digits10?
Some other related questions in stackoverflow made me think it is the maximum precision of a double, but

- The following prototype starts working (sucess is true) when precision is greater that 17 ( == 2+numeric_limits::digits10)
- With STLPort, readDouble==infinity at the end; with microsoft's STL, readDouble == 0.0.
- Has this prototype any kind of meaning :) ?

Here is the prototype:

```
#include <float.h>
#include <limits>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  std::ostringstream os;
  //int digit10=std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10; // ==15
  //int digit=std::numeric_limits<double>::digits; // ==53
  os << std::setprecision(17);
  os << DBL_MAX;
  std::cout << os.str();
  std::stringbuf sb(os.str());
  std::istream is(&sb);
  double readDouble=0.0;
  is >> readDouble;
  bool success = fabs(DBL_MAX-readDouble)<0.1;
}
```

Comment: Related: [Decimal precision of floats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310276/decimal-precision-of-floats) and [Is it 6 or 7.22?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30688422/183120).

Answer (score 18):

`numeric_limits::digits10` is the number of decimal digits that can be held without loss.

For example `numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits10` is 2. This means that an unsigned char can hold 0..99 without loss. ***If*** it were 3 it could hold 0..999, but as we all know it can only hold 0..255.

[This manual page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/af6x78h6.aspx) has an example for floating point numbers, which (when shortened) shows that

```
cout << numeric_limits<float>::digits10 <<endl;
float f = (float)99999999; // 8 digits
cout.precision ( 10 );
cout << "The float is; " << f << endl;
```

prints

```
6
The float is; 100000000
```

Comment: Why is  there 8 digits instead of 7 in the float example, because it could have been enough to show the problem? Is there another reason behind this ?

Comment: @Guillaume07 As far as I can tell, all 7 digit *whole* numbers survive the "double->float->double" conversion intact. The smallest whole number that fails is 16777217, which is 8 digits. An explanation of why numeric_limits<float>::digits10 is 6 can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310276/decimal-precision-of-floats

Comment: @AndrewStein `is the number of decimal digits that can be held without loss` maybe we should say up 2 sign ? after all we can't represent -99 as unsigned char

Answer (score 7):

numeric_limits::digits10 specifies the number of decimal digits to the left of the decimal point you can represent without a loss of precision. Each type will have a different number of representable decimal values.

Comment: it doesn't mean that the number can hold 15 digits after the decimal if there is no number except 0 before the radix point ?

Comment: This answer is incorrect. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13103444/183120).

Answer (score 6):

The '53' is the bit width of the [significand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand) that your type (double) holds. The '15' is the number of *decimal* digits that can be represented *safely* with that kind of precision.

Answer (score 6):

See this very readable paper:
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2005.pdf

Although DBL_MAX ( = std::numeric_limits::digits10 = 15 digits) is the minimum guaranteed number of digits for a double, the DBL_MAXDIG10 value (= 17 digits) proposed in the paper has the useful properties:

- Of being the minimum number of digits needed to survive a round-trip to string form and back and get the same double in the end.
- Of being the minimum number of digits needed to convert the double 
   to string form and show different strings every time you get (A != B) in code. 
   With 16 or fewer digits, you can get doubles that are not equal in code, 
   but when they are converted to string form they are the same 
   (which will give the case where they are different when compared in the code, 
   but a log file will show them as identical - very confusing and hard to debug!)

When you compare values (e.g. by reviewing them manually by diff'ing two log files) we should remember that digits 1-15 are ALWAYS valid, but differences in the 16th and 17th digits *MAY* be junk.

Answer (score 2):

`digits10` is for conversion: string → double → string
`max_digits10` is for conversion: double → string → double

In your program, you are using the conversion (double → string → double). You should use `max_digits10` instead of `digits10`.

For more details about `digits10` and `max_digits10`, you can read:

- [difference explained by stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458355/what-is-the-purpose-of-max-digits10-and-how-is-it-different-from-digits10)
- [digits10](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10)
- [max_digits10](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_digits10)