# Correct Way to set maximum double precision for ostringstream

Tags: c++

By referring to

[How do I print a double value with full precision using cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout)

and

[What is the meaning of numeric_limits<double>::digits10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747470/what-is-the-meaning-of-numeric-limitsdoubledigits10)

I am slightly confused.

Shall I used :

```
ss.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10);
```

or

```
ss.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 2);
```

to get maximum double precision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depend on number of "decimal component" you have in data.

std::numeric_limits::digits10 will give the maximum number of "floating component"

ios_base::precision specifies the number of digits (decimal + float components) to display.

if your decimal component is always less than 100 (-99 to 99), code below always give maximum precision.

```
ss.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 2);
```

Comment: Oh. Is nice to see you here. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [What is the meaning of numeric_limits<double>::digits10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747470/what-is-the-meaning-of-numeric-limitsdoubledigits10), specifically the highest voted answer, `std::numericlimits<double>::digits10` is:

> the maximum number of digits you can represent without loss of precision.

That means if you set ss.precision to that, these floating point digits will be accurate; if you set it to that +2 you will still display that+2 digits but the last two aren't guaranteed to be accurately calculated.

For arbitray precision, if that's what you need, take a look at [mpir](http://www.mpir.org), [gmp](http://www.gmplib.org), [mpfr](http://www.mpfr.org/)