# Buffer reading and writing floats

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I write a float to a buffer, it does not read back the same value:

```
> var b = new Buffer(4);
undefined
> b.fill(0)
undefined
> b.writeFloatBE(3.14159,0)
undefined
> b.readFloatBE(0)
3.141590118408203
> 
(^C again to quit)
>
```

Why?

EDIT:

My working theory is that because javascript stores all numbers as double precision, it's possible that the buffer implementation does not properly zero the other 4 bytes of the double when it reads the float back in:

```
> var b = new Buffer(4)
undefined
> b.fill(0)
undefined
> b.writeFloatBE(0.1,0)
undefined
> b.readFloatBE(0)
0.10000000149011612
>
```

I think it's telling that we have zeros for 7 digits past the decimal (well, 8 actually) and then there's garbage. I think there's a bug in the node buffer code that reads these floats. That's what I think. This is node version 0.10.26.

Comment: It's a float, not a double. If you need the precision of a double, write a double instead.

Comment: Probably should be using the byte size specific read / write methods.

Comment: @self: I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying that `writeFloatBE` should not be used to write a floating point number to a buffer?

Comment: @Kevin: [`writeDoubleBE`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_writedoublebe_value_offset_noassert) is your friend.

Comment: @Qantas: if I'm implementing a platform neutral wire format, and the other side is expecting a 4 byte float, I can't exactly do that, can I?

Comment: @Qantas: but you're right, `writeDoubleBE` works fine.

Comment: @Kevin: well... that's the closest to 3.14159 for a float. If you're looking for some way to display the least number of decimal places to represent a single-precision float, that's a slightly different question.

Comment: I still don't get it. How is `3.141590118408203` closer to `3.14159`? It's not like I'm dividing numbers, which I would understand could create long approximations. It seems to me the implementation is not zero filling, or is reading in garbage, or something like that.

Comment: It's not closer, just the *closest* representation that is achievable as a float. This is an unfortunate restriction inherent to single-precision floats.

Comment: @RobertMitchell: I don't believe it, see my update on the question for the reason why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readFloat` in node is [implemented](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.33-release/src/node_buffer.cc#L426) in c++ and bytes are interpreted exactly the way your compiler stores/reads them. I doubt there is a bug here. What I think is that "7 digits" is incorrect assumption for float. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310276/decimal-precision-of-floats) suggest 6 digits (and it's the value of `std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10` ) so the result of `readFloatBE` is within expected error

Answer (score 5):

Floating point numbers ("floats") are never a fully-accurate representation of a number; this is a common feature that is seen across multiple languages, not just JavaScript / NodeJS. For example, I encountered something similar in C# when using `float` instead of `double`.

Double-precision floating point numbers are more accurate and should better meet your expectations. Try changing the above code to write to the buffer as a double instead of a float:

```
var b = new Buffer(8);
b.fill(0);
b.writeDoubleBE(3.14159, 0);
b.readDoubleBE(0);
```

This will return:

```
3.14159
```

EDIT:

Wikipedia has some pretty good articles on floats and doubles, if you're interested in learning more:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

SECOND EDIT:

Here is some code that illustrates the limitation of the single-precision vs. double-precision float formats, using typed arrays. Hopefully this can act as proof of this limitation, as I'm having a hard time explaining in words:

```
var floats32 = new Float32Array(1),
    floats64 = new Float64Array(1),
    n = 3.14159;

floats32[0] = n;
floats64[0] = n;

console.log("float", floats32[0]);
console.log("double", floats64[0]);
```

This will print:

```
float 3.141590118408203
double 3.14159
```

Also, if my understanding is correct, single-precision floating point numbers can store up to 7 *total* digits (significant digits), not 7 digits after the decimal point. This means that they should be accurate up to 7 total significant digits, which lines up with your results (`3.14159` has 6 significant digits, `3.141590118408203` => first 7 digits => `3.141590` => `3.141590 === 3.14159`).

Comment: please see comments below the question. I'm implementing a wire format, so the other side expects 4 bytes. I can't just send 8 bytes. And, floats are precise to 7 digits past the decimal (vs. 17 for doubles). I've only got 5 digits past the decimal, so I still don't buy into this "doubles are more accurate" argument.

Comment: Interesting...I'll have to think about this one for a bit and get back to you :)

Comment: You can adjust `n` in my code sample above to verify the "7 total digits" piece. For example, `n = 12345678.12345678` results in `float 12345678`
`double 12345678.12345678`