# There is no real float type in Node.js/V8?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I try to store one `float` value through `Buffer` in `Node.js`

```
> f = 3.3
3.3
> var buf = new Buffer(32)
> buf.writeFloatBE(f);
4
> g = buf.readFloatBE();
3.299999952316284
```

Then I found the stored value `g` after `readFloatBE()` is NOT equal to the original `f`.

After further investigation, those two buffer values stored `g` and `f` are same.

```
> var buf1 = new Buffer(4); buf1.writeFloatBE(f); buf1
<Buffer 40 53 33 33>
> var buf2 = new Buffer(4); buf2.writeFloatBE(g); buf2
<Buffer 40 53 33 33>
```

According to this [Buffer reading and writing floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097835/buffer-reading-and-writing-floats), we know the `writeDoulbeBE` should be used here.

```
> var buf3 = new Buffer(8);
> buf3.writeDoubleBE(f);
8
> h = buf3.readDoubleBE();
3.3
> h === f
true
```

I want to know why the `float` type is not used in `Node.js` or `V8`? Refer to the [code](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/include/v8.h#L3100-L3104) from `V8`

```
  // Fast primitive setters
  V8_INLINE void Set(bool value);
  V8_INLINE void Set(double i);
  V8_INLINE void Set(int32_t i);
  V8_INLINE void Set(uint32_t i);
```

It seems there is NO `float` type in `V8`, any reason of this design or am I missing something? In which case, should this function `writeFloatBE()` be used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It seems there is NO `float` type in V8

Yes, and this is by design: There is no `float` type in JavaScript either. *All numbers* are `double`s [as specified by the ECMAScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type).

Your number `f` is therefore `3.3` with `double` precision, while `g` only has `float` precision. As you can see, that's not the same double as `f`. The same would happen if you used one of the `buf.writeInt…` methods, the result after reading it would only be `3` not `3.3`.

> In which case, should the function `writeFloatBE()` be used?

Yes, of course it should be used, whenever you want to store numbers with `float` precision in a buffer. If you want to store `f` with full precision, use [`writeDoubleBE`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_writedoublebe_value_offset_noassert) instead.