# Rounding issue when printf'ing floats

Tags: c, floating-point

Can someone explain why C's `printf` is rounding down in the second case?

```
printf("%.03f", 79.2025); /* "79.203" */
printf("%.03f", 22.7565); /* "22.756" */
```

Comment: What "behavior" did you expect?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude correct rounding, I presume. Isn\`t it obvious? The more interesting question is why the heck this got downvoted.

Comment: I thought it was obvious too, but it seems I was mistaken :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OP's post hints at:

```
printf("%.03f", 79.2025); /* "79.203" */
printf("%.03f", 22.7565); /* "22.756" */
```

Why is one value rounding up and the other down?

---

Numbers like `79.2025` and `22.7565` are not exactly representable as `double` on your system.  Instead nearby values are encoded.

The 2 likely *exact* `doubles` values are

```
79.2025000000000005684341886080801486968994140625
22.756499999999999062083588796667754650115966796875
```

This is due to using a [binary floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) encoding.  Most systems use binary floating-point although C does allow bases: 16, 10, and other powers-of 2.  (I have never work on "other powers-of 2" systems.)

---

Printing those 2 values to the nearest 0.001 as `printf("%.03f"...` directs is below, which matches OP's results.

```
79.203  // 79.20250000000000056... rounds up   as 50000000000056... > 50000000000000...
22.756  // 22.75649999999999906... rounds down as 49999999999906... < 50000000000000...
```

---

The below is also interesting.  Both 1.0625 and 1.1875  are *exactly* encode-able as `double`.  Yet one typically rounds up and the other rounds down given the usual "round ties to even" rule.  Depending on various things, your output may vary, yet the below output is common.

```
printf("%.03f", 1.0625); /* "1.062" */
printf("%.03f", 1.1875); /* "1.188" */
```

---

Using a **different precision** of *binary* floating point types does **not** alter the fundamental issue: FP assigned  a decimal value in code in the form of x.xxx5 rarely have the matching exact value.  About 50% of them will be more than x.xxx5 and the other less.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%.03f", 79.2025); /* "79.203" */

printf("%.03f", 22.7565); /* "22.756" */
```

3 character after point

```
printf("%6.3f", 79.2025);  /* "79.203" */

printf("%6.3f", 22.7565);  /* "22.756" */
```

2character + . + 3character = 6 character

Answer (score 0):

This is [common behaviour in floating point precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310276/decimal-precision-of-floats); it's not perfect, since there are a finite number of bits used to represent a value. At some point, decimal places become so small that they exceed the precision that's available for a given bit width.

Perhaps seek a higher-resolution decimal, such as a `long double`.

Comment: The two numbers in OP's post have already type `double`; the `"%f"` printf specifier expects a value of type `double`. Perhaps you meant `long double` (79.2025L and "%Lf")?

Comment: I've corrected the post, thank you. Clearly I've spent too long in the world of Java!