# std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 = number of digits on the right or left to the radix point?

Tags: c++, double

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format say that double can handle 16 digits of precision to the right part of the number, is digits10 show this number ?

Comment: Did you see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747470/what-is-the-meaning-of-numeric-limitsdoubledigits10 ?

Comment: yes but I'm a little bit suprised because it seems digits10 show the number to the left, and wikipedia says that number of digits to the right its 15/16, so I arrive to the conclusion that both right and left side of a double precision number can handle 15 or 16 digits ?that's weird

Comment: all right I just wanted to have this confirmation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it's just the number of meaningful digits. Point. You can have `12345678901234.5` or `0.0000123456789012345`.

Comment: so 0 are not taking into account into this 15 digits ? even if not at the end

Comment: Nope :) A double is some digits, and a power of ten, so your digits are 123456789012345, and they can be multiplied by 10e-15 or by 10e18, doesn't change anything in precision

Answer (score 5):

`std::numeric_limits<T>::digit10` is the number of decimal digits you can get back when converting a string with a decimal value to `T` and back to a string again. The count starts at the most significant non-zero digit, independent of where the decimal point is located (as long as you don't conflict with the range restrictions of `T`, of course). That is, leading and trailing zeros don't matter.

Comment: std::string str = "12345679012.124678";
 double back = boost::lexical_cast<double>( str );
 std::string strs =boost::lexical_cast<std::string>( back );

Comment: in my above example there is no loss but number's significand digits is greater than std::numeric_limits<T>::digit10

Comment: The `digits10` works for all values. If you go lucky you can get up to `digits` decimal digits right: Any number which can be represented as (-1)<sup>_sign_</sup> * _mantissa_ * 2 <sup>_exponent_</sup> can be exact (as long as you stay within the bounds of what can be represented).

Comment: just a doubt about your sentence: "The count starts at the BIGGEST non-zero digit" at the first or the biggest ?

Comment: I should have written "most significant non-zero digit" but failed to come up with the term.

Comment: Fixed now! Thanks for the answer.